# Failing to access an angular file outside of asset folder

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

i'm having difficulty with this small project that should read a log and display it in a table.

this is the structure of the project
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tErPP.png)
inside the LOG folder i should be able to read `motore.log` from my DataService, but i always get a 404 NOT FOUND ERROR:

Here's the function that does the get:

```
    baseDirLog = "LOG/motore.log"
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getLog() {
        return this.http.get(this.baseDirLog, {responseType : 'text'}).pipe(
            map(response =>                
                JSON.stringify(response)))
    }
```

and i have modified like this the `angluar.json` file

```
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {"glob": "**/*", "input": "LOG", "output": "./assets/"}
            ],
```

moving the file into the asset folder solves the problem, but i need the file in that specific LOG folder

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change the output line in angular.json, like this:

```
         "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          {"glob": "**/*", "input": "LOG", "output": "./LOG/"}
        ],
```

Comment: Ludovico, can you press the left button (upvote) to put my answer as correct? This is the form that we recognize what answer is correct. When you click a green signal appears below of my answer